# solve error in controller class for wsdl generated apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi this my generated apex code can any help me on writing apex controller i am tring controller class like this but getting error:

```
public class tempuriOrg {
    public class SubtractResponse_element {
        public Integer SubtractResult;
        private String[] SubtractResult_type_info = new String[]{'SubtractResult','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SubtractResult'};
    }
    public class Divide_element {
        public Integer intA;
        public Integer intB;
        private String[] intA_type_info = new String[]{'intA','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] intB_type_info = new String[]{'intB','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'intA','intB'};
    }
    public class Multiply_element {
        public Integer intA;
        public Integer intB;
        private String[] intA_type_info = new String[]{'intA','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] intB_type_info = new String[]{'intB','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'intA','intB'};
    }
    public class Subtract_element {
        public Integer intA;
        public Integer intB;
        private String[] intA_type_info = new String[]{'intA','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] intB_type_info = new String[]{'intB','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'intA','intB'};
    }
    public class AddResponse_element {
        public Integer AddResult;
        private String[] AddResult_type_info = new String[]{'AddResult','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'AddResult'};
    }
    public class Add_element {
        public Integer intA;
        public Integer intB;
        private String[] intA_type_info = new String[]{'intA','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] intB_type_info = new String[]{'intB','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'intA','intB'};
    }
    public class DivideResponse_element {
        public Integer DivideResult;
        private String[] DivideResult_type_info = new String[]{'DivideResult','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'DivideResult'};
    }
    public class MultiplyResponse_element {
        public Integer MultiplyResult;
        private String[] MultiplyResult_type_info = new String[]{'MultiplyResult','http://tempuri.org/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'MultiplyResult'};
    }
    public class CalculatorSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/', 'tempuriOrg'};
        public Integer Multiply(Integer intA,Integer intB) {
            tempuriOrg.Multiply_element request_x = new tempuriOrg.Multiply_element();
            request_x.intA = intA;
            request_x.intB = intB;
            tempuriOrg.MultiplyResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, tempuriOrg.MultiplyResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrg.MultiplyResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/Multiply',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'Multiply',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'MultiplyResponse',
              'tempuriOrg.MultiplyResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.MultiplyResult;
        }
        public Integer Divide(Integer intA,Integer intB) {
            tempuriOrg.Divide_element request_x = new tempuriOrg.Divide_element();
            request_x.intA = intA;
            request_x.intB = intB;
            tempuriOrg.DivideResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, tempuriOrg.DivideResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrg.DivideResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/Divide',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'Divide',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'DivideResponse',
              'tempuriOrg.DivideResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.DivideResult;
        }
        public Integer Subtract(Integer intA,Integer intB) {
            tempuriOrg.Subtract_element request_x = new tempuriOrg.Subtract_element();
            request_x.intA = intA;
            request_x.intB = intB;
            tempuriOrg.SubtractResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, tempuriOrg.SubtractResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrg.SubtractResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/Subtract',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'Subtract',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'SubtractResponse',
              'tempuriOrg.SubtractResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.SubtractResult;
        }
        public Integer Add(Integer intA,Integer intB) {
            tempuriOrg.Add_element request_x = new tempuriOrg.Add_element();
            request_x.intA = intA;
            request_x.intB = intB;
            tempuriOrg.AddResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, tempuriOrg.AddResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrg.AddResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/Add',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'Add',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'AddResponse',
              'tempuriOrg.AddResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.AddResult;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my controller class

```
public class bodmas{
public integer intA{get;set;}
public integer intB{get;set;}
public integer result{get;set;}

public integer additoin(){
result = tempuriOrg.Add(intA,intB);
} 
public integer Subtraction(){
result = tempuriOrg.Subtract(intA,intB);
} 
public integer division(){
result = tempuriOrg.Divide(intA,intB);
} 
}
```

my error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: tempuriOrg.Add(Integer, Integer) at line 7 column 10
```

Visulaforce code:

```
<apex:page controller="bodmas">
<apex:form >
INTEGERA:<apex:inputtext value="{!inta}"/><br/>
INTEGERB:<apex:inputtext value="{!intb}"/><br/>
addition:<apex:commandbutton value="addition" action="{!additoin}"/><br/>
sutraction:<apex:commandbutton value="sutraction" action="{!Subtraction}"/><br/>
division:<apex:commandbutton value="division" action="{!division}"/><br/>
result:<apex:outputtext value="{!result}"/><br/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking addition as an example, it looks like the method you want to call is this:

```
public Integer Add(Integer intA,Integer intB)
```

which is a method of the `CalculatorSoap` inner class. What I believe you would want to do is create an instance of that class, and then call that method:

```
public class bodmas{
    public integer intA{get;set;}
    public integer intB{get;set;}
    public integer result{get;set;}

    public PageReference additoin(){
        tempuriOrg.CalculatorSoap calculator = new tempuriOrg.CalculatorSoap();
        result = calculator.Add(intA,intB);
        return NULL;
    } 
                    ⋮
}
```

Comment: Thank you @martin your code working fine but while running in visualforce showing error: "Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: java.lang.Integer "

Comment: Updated My visualforce page above please check once why error came

Comment: When you call an action from a commandButton, the return type of the method in the controller has to be `PageReference`. If you return `NULL`, the visualforce page should refresh with the new value of result.

Comment: excellent. I'm glad I could help.